# Regex to match string of format DigitOperandDigit

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a simple Java Regex to see if a given String **contains** the following pattern:

```
DigitOperandDigit
```

Digit being a number from 0 to 9 and operand is any one of `+-/*`.

Examples:

```
1+1
2/4
```

Comment: Do some research, try few things and post when you need help with the code you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression should work:

```
\d[*/+-]\d
```

And in use:

```
if (string.matches("\d[*/+-]\d"))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using "[0-9][*/+-][0-9]" and it didn't work. Not sure why but thanks. Yours is working.